# Installed gcc49 via homebrew, but gcc -v still shows I have gcc42?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, terminal, homebrew

When I enter

`brew install gcc49`

I see:

`Warning: gcc49-4.9.0 already installed`

and when I check my gcc version with `gcc -v`

`Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix`

Is there something else I have to do besides install gcc49 via homebrew to be able to use it?

Comment: Invoke it using the full path?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Would you mind giving an example of how I could do that?

Comment: Type `gcc<TAB>` where `<TAB>` is the tab key. Key hitting the tab key and see if different things pop out.

Comment: @jxh I see gcc and gccmakedep

Comment: `/path/to/where/gcc/was/installed/gcc`

Comment: You could try `which gcc` to see what executable is used w/o absolute path. Probably that's something you dont expect.

Comment: I found the answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280834/how-do-i-do-i-run-gcc-49-with-just-gcc-on-osx