# How do I do I run gcc-49 with just 'gcc' on OSX?

Tags: macos, gcc, gcc4.9

I recently installed gcc 4.9, with a previous version of gcc that was installed by default before.

When I type gcc, the previous version of gcc runs. How could I make my newly installed gcc 4.9 run when I type gcc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this:

```
cd /usr/bin
mv gcc gcc-old
ln -s gcc-4.9 gcc
```

Or you should have a look to gcc_select

Comment: If gcc-4.9 is installed outside of /usr/bin, I should replace "gcc-4.9" with the path to gcc-4.9, right?

Comment: Yes, you just need to create a symbolic link (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link)

Comment: Alrighty. I'll give this a try and tell you how it goes!

Comment: Please make a copy of your gcc in /usr/bin I have updated the solution

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the tip

Comment: This is a poor answer as messing with files in a system-controlled directory is ill-advised.  If `gcc-49` is installed in `/usr/local/bin` then better is to create a hard link to `gcc` in `/usr/local/bin`, and ensure `/usr/local/bin` appears *before* `/usr/bin` in `$PATH`.